# Feature importance after Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

When comparing feature importances across variables, how can I interpret the results. Example; Feature 1 has a FI score of 0.2 and Feature 2 has a FI score of 0.02. Can I say feature 1 is 10 times more important?

I have a table and dictionary of all feature importances so wondering how to interpret them between themselves.